# Local sites are opening slowly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have ubuntu 18.04 and configured some sites in local but sites are opening slowly in Chrome while opening the site.

Configuration of Laptop.

RAM - 16 GB
i7 Processor
1 TB HDD
1.5GHz

Thanks for support

Comment: Local sites ? Are they just plain html, or are there other things involved (database, java, ,,,) ?

Comment: They are in magento sites and involved(html,PHP) things.

Answer (score 0):

First your processor with 1.5Ghz frequency for sure could not leads to smooth performance.

Else:

- Delete your chrome history including cookies and all cached saved data.
- Then, in ur browser change **localhost:port** to **127.0.0.1:port**
- Finally disable **Compression** in the IIS panel and apply it.